# SKSpriteNode replace with SKTexture

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

My problem is that when I play my game, I lose my life even if the enemy does not touch my character, but flies very close to him. I understand that the problem is that the transparent space of my character is in contact with the enemy's transparent space.

I want to do as recommended in the [SKPhysicsBody documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody#2852041). How can I implement this using my current code?

```
func madEnemy() {

    let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1..<6)

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy\(randomNumber)")

    enemy.position = CGPoint(
        x: cameraRect.maxX + enemy.size.width/2,
        y: CGFloat.random(
            min: cameraRect.minY + enemy.size.height/2,
            max: cameraRect.maxY - enemy.size.height/2))
    enemy.zPosition = 50
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    addChild(enemy)

    let actionMove =
        SKAction.moveBy(x: -(size.width + enemy.size.width), y: 0, duration: 2.0)
    let actionRemove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    enemy.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionRemove]))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a `SKTexture` object from your image first, then create a `SKSpriteNode` using that texture in order to use the texture for sizing the `SKPhysicsBody` or your node.

```
func madEnemy() {

    let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1..<6)

    let enemyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "enemy\(randomNumber)")
    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyTexture)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTexture, size: CGSize(width: enemy.size.width, height: enemy.size.height))

    enemy.position = CGPoint(
        x: cameraRect.maxX + enemy.size.width/2,
        y: CGFloat.random(
            min: cameraRect.minY + enemy.size.height/2,
            max: cameraRect.maxY - enemy.size.height/2))
    enemy.zPosition = 50
    enemy.name = "enemy"
    addChild(enemy)

    let actionMove =
        SKAction.moveBy(x: -(size.width + enemy.size.width), y: 0, duration: 2.0)
    let actionRemove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    enemy.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionRemove]))
}
```

Comment: thank you! should I add that code from Apple website?

Comment: @SheronLi where would you want to add code from the documentation? You should simply use the code provided in my answer

Comment: thank you! Strange, but the enemies do not fly, but seem to fall.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: @SheronLi that shouldn't have been affected by the `SKPhysicsBody` added. Was your code identical to your previous version other than the changes I made to it and was it working fine before?

Comment: I didn't change your code. Just copied and pasted. I also don't understand why. Maybe need more information?

Comment: It works after I added `enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false` Thank you!